# Javascript as illustration of Java beans

Tags: java

[image]

This is from the JavaBeans Specification (https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/).

What astonishes me is that it mentions JavaScript. By the way, even Javascript (which is even more strange).

Anyway, could you tell me why it is mentioned here? And how it illustrates beans?

Comment: What's astonishing about mentioning JavaScript?

Comment: It says "in scripting environments". Javascript is an example of such.

Comment: But it is about Java beans. Well, let it be illustrated by a scripting environment rather than Java. What is contrasted here? That they can assign something to a variable? In Java we also can do that. That they don't use getters and setters? Well, they do use them.

Why mingling JavaScript here at all?

Comment: I'm bad at JavaScript. Is it here just because JavaScript doesn't ensure encapsulation?

Comment: "*tell me why it is mentioned here?*" - that can be (better) answered by the authors - we can only guess why they did it. Also worth remembering that both Java and Javascript are of similar age.

Comment: Well, how can I understand that specification. Can I understand that JavaScript was just a good example of violation of encapsulation principle back in 1996?

Comment: Please don't post texts as images

Comment: The point is not about violating encapsulation, the point is about interoperability between Java and scripting environments such as Javascript. There are various situations where you want to expose an API to a scripting language wherein an object's properties can be accessed through the scripting language. Using a standardised form for designing classes in Java (i.e. beans) allows the interop code to be generated automatically instead of having to be written by hand.

Comment: Originally, Java was intended to run as applets inside a web browser, and JavaScript was intended to provide integration between Java applets and the browser DOM. JavaBeans was intended to provide a mechanism for tools to manipulate Java objects dynamically, without knowing anything about their compile time type. I’m oversimplifying a bit, but this is how they were marketed.

Comment: @Kifsif and still is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not support (buit-in, transparent) properties (as opposed to python, for example). The concept of properties is added by the JavaBeans specification. Beans were originally intended to be used in visual application builders (see the introduction section of the document you linked to).

These were much like the core concept still in use by game engines - you define entities with properties, usually in a 2-column table with name and value. And you define the behavior of these entities, usually in a scripting language.

The examples are written with such a system in mind, and make sense from that perspective.

In the script code, a 'property' is accessed as if it were a public field. In the Java code implementing the bean, the setters and getters would still be invoked automatically. The precise names of the getters and setters wouldn't matter, for this use case - the user never uses them directly. The specification still recommends conventions for naming, and specifies expectations on exception behavior etc.